# Cómo cargar una web con Google Analytics en mi webView JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, google-analytics

**Hola**

El problema que presentó radica al cargar una web la cuál trabaja con Google Analytics en mi webView no me genera la conexión o visualización de la web desde mi webView como una visita. Me explico mejor estoy haciendo un proyecto dónde requiero que en mi app Java poder cargar una web referente al mismo proyecto dentro de la app pero que la visita de esta misma se contabilice en Google Analytics. Soy nuevo usando la herramienta WebView y WebEngine y espero ustedes me ayuden en mi problema.

```
public class browser extends JFXPanel{
private WebEngine engine;
private String sysProxy, sysProxyPort;

public browser(){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            WebView view = new WebView();

            sysProxy = System.getProperty("https.proxy");
            sysProxyPort = System.getProperty("https.proxyPort");

            engine = view.getEngine();
            setScene(new Scene(view));
        }
    });
    setVisible(true);
}

private void setProxySystem(){
    System.setProperty("https.proxy", sysProxy);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", sysProxyPort);
}

public void loadURL(final String url, String userAgent){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String tmp =toURL(url);
            if(tmp == null){
                tmp = toURL(url);
            }

            //engine.setUserAgent(userAgent);

            engine.setOnError(new EventHandler<WebErrorEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(WebErrorEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("ocurrio un error al conectar");
                }
            });



            engine.load(tmp);




        }
    });

}

private String toURL(String str){
    try {
        return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(browser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad `Google Analytics` implementado en una pàgina web que cargas en un WebView es independiente de habilitarlo en la aplicación.

Dentro de https://analytics.google.com/analytics/ , debes asegurar crear tu propiedad y obtener el script que sera insertado en tu página web para dar seguimiento mediante `Google Analytics`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De lado del `WebView` en realidad solo necesitas habilitar JavaScript para que el script mencionado anteriormente pueda funcionar y realizar el registro de datos desde la pagina web cargada dentro del `WebView`:

```
WebView myWebView = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = myWebView.getEngine();
webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

---

Otro metodo para realizar el registro de datos se describe aquì:

**[Agregar Analytics a tu Android App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4)**

encontré esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés que implementa Google Analytics usandola clase `GoogleAnalyticsTracker`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988618/android-webview-app-and-google-analytics

Comment: Amigo esto mismo acabo de hacer, pero no funciona no me genera el contado en Google Analytics

Comment: ¿Si carga la página en el WebView? ,Que te parece si primeramente cargas la página en el navegador y te aseguras realice el "hit", probablemente es un problema de la página.

Comment: Amigo si carga la página en el webView y de paso ya lo probé y si hace conteo tanto desde mi teléfono como desde mi PC . No si sea porque tal vez el scripts haga peticiones a servidores externos y esto se prohiba.

Comment: @Abraham.P desde tu telefono te encuentras dentro de alguna red interna, o debajo de un  proxy? eso podría ser el problema.

Comment: Amigo el proxy pero webView no debería tomar el proxy local de la máquina. Además creo que no me está generando cookies y por lo tanto la cookie de Analytics no se obtiene

Comment: Pero a usted amigo le hace el conteo en Analytics ??

Comment: Abraham viste mi mensaje? Comentaba que, el ùnico detalle es habilitar Javascript en el WebView, acabo de agregar otro metodo para realizar el seguimiento, revisa esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17990908/250260